# My java script code makes all of the other codes stop working. If, Else loops

Tags: javascript, html, loops, if-statement

So I am trying to make a game where you choose your own adventure. But the loop I made with prompt does not work and makes the other code not work. I am new a java script so I am still trying to figure everything out. If anyone is able to help, I would appreciate it. The code I am using is

```
function myFunction() {
var option = prompt("Please enter Bat or Metal");
if (option == "bat" or "Bat" ) {
    document.getElementById("path1c").innerHTML =
    "Congrats! You killed the creature, but got bitten by the creature.";
else {
    document.getElementById("path1c").innerHTML =
    "Congrats! You killed the creature and were not harmed.";
}
}
```

Also I am using a button that calls myFunction on click, so that a prompt will show up.

Comment: First lesson is that `java` and `javascript` are different languages and are not related in any way except that they have similar names

Comment: Javascript is very fragile. It's very common that if you make one simple syntax error, all the code on the page will stop working. The most common mistake (and yes, you've made this one above) is that your opening and closing braces ( { } ) don't match up. You've got more opening braces '{' than closing '}'.

Comment: `or` is not a javascript operator, you probably want something like this: `if (option == "bat" || option == "Bat" ) `

Comment: I guess this should be obvious from the previous comments, but you need to spend some time learn the fundamentals of javascript controls structures, not posting on SO.  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Control_Structures

Comment: @Kon Besides the names, JavaScript and Java are related indeed. When Brendan Eich designed the language, there was an order from the company high level that said, make it look like Java. There are many evidances that could proove it in a way. For example, in an interview Brendan also admitted that `Date` in JavaScript was manully ported from `java.util.Date`.

Comment: I'd still argue the two languages are not related, they have similarities by design, but the have never, even closely, been part of one system. Apart from similar syntax and some borrowed features the name was chosen and licensed from Sun for marketing reasons. [Source] (https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/A_Short_History_of_JavaScript). The naming  licensing is as close as you will get to a relationship. Was javascript inspired by Java, yes, but there is no actual relationship.

Answer (score 0):

1. JS doesn't have `or` keyword, should be `||`:

   ```
   if (option == "bat" || option == "Bat" ) {
   ```
2. Syntax wrong on `if/else`, brackets must match. You missed a `}` before `else`, should be:

   ```
   if(/*condition*/) {
     // something here
   } else {
     // something here
   }
   ```

No offense, but judging from your code, especially the usage of `or`, you're just **guessing** the language and bidding your luck. You won't go long this way. What you really need to do now is to grab a fundamental book and read.

---

EDIT:

JavaScript and Java are related indeed. When [**Brendan Eich**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich) designed the language, there was an order from the company high level that said, make it look like Java. There are many evidances that could proove it, explicitly or implicitly. For example, in many places Brendan admitted that `Date` in JavaScript was manully ported from `java.util.Date` (like [this answer on Quora](http://www.quora.com/Did-JavaScript-evolve-from-another-product-or-scripting-language/answer/Brendan-Eich)).